# I went to donate to someone, but did not have any cash with me; how is this judged?

Tags: judgements, deeds

I came across a situation after Friday prayers. I crossed a person and I had the intention of donating to him. But when I dug into my pockets, I found I didn't have any cash with me. I felt bad and walked away.

What does the Hadith say about our intention in reference to action? 
How are we judged in the eyes of Allah swt?

Side notes : http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/articles/156996/the-intention-is-the-foundation-of-every-action

Comment: Is there a reason why you would want to donate to him for crossing him by mistake? Do you crossing him as passing by him or interrupting their salah?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the presence of following Hadiths, I need not add any further explanation

> 'Abdullah bin 'Abbas (May Allah be pleased with them) reported:
>   Messenger of Allah (sws) said that Allah, the Glorious, said: "Verily,
>   Allah (SWT) has ordered that the good and the bad deeds be written
>   down. Then He explained it clearly how (to write): **He who intends to
>   do a good deed but he does not do it, then Allah records it for him as
>   a full good deed**, but if he carries out his intention, then Allah
>   the Exalted, writes it down for him as from ten to seven hundred
>   folds, and even more. But if he intends to do an evil act and has not
>   done it, then Allah writes it down with Him as a full good deed, but
>   if he intends it and has done it, Allah writes it down as one bad
>   deed".

[[Al-Bukhari and Muslim].](http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/1/11)

Another hadith that makes it clear that even wishful thinking with good intention has merits.

> Abu Kabshah Al-Anmari narrated that the Messenger of Allah (s.a.w)
>   said: "There are three things for which I swear and narrate to you
>   about, so remember it." He said: "The wealth of a slave (of Allah)
>   shall not be decreased by charity, no slave (of Allah) suffers
>   injustice and is patient with it except that Allah adds to his honor;
>   no slave (of Allah) opens up a door to begging except that Allah opens
>   a door for him to poverty"- or a statement similar- "And I shall
>   narrate to you a narration, so remember it." He said: "The world is
>   only for four persons: A slave whom Allah provides with wealth and
>   knowledge, so he has Taqwa of his Lord with it, nurtures the ties of
>   kinship with it, and he knows that Allah has a right in it. So this is
>   the most virtuous rank. And a slave whom Allah provides with
>   knowledge, but He does not provide with wealth. So he has a truthful
>   intent, saying: **'If I had wealth, then I would do the deeds of
>   so-and-so with it.' He has his intention, so their rewards are the
>   same.** And a slave whom Allah provides with wealth, but He does not
>   provide him with knowledge. [So he] spends his wealth rashly without
>   knowledge, nor having Taqwa of his Lord, nor nurturing the ties of
>   kinship, and he does not know that Allah has a right in it. So this is
>   the most despicable rank. And a slave whom Allah does not provide with
>   wealth nor knowledge, so he says: 'If I had wealth, then I would do
>   the deeds of so-and-so with it.' He has his intention, so their sin is
>   the same."

[[Al-Tirmidhi]](http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/36/22)